# An "easy" way to construct an epimorphism from S4 to S3

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, group-homomorphism, epimorphisms

I'm trying to construct an epimorphism φ from S4 to S3 such that:

> H = ker(φ) = {(1),(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)}

where H is a normal subgroup of S4, contained in A4 and isomorphic to the Klein 4-group.

I've tried to look up the question here and I've found out some similar threads like these ones:

- [An epimorphism from S4 to S3 having the kernel isomorphic to Klein four-group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/106777/an-epimorphism-from-s-4-to-s-3-having-the-kernel-isomorphic-to-klein-fou)

- [Constructing a homomorphism from S4 to S3 that satisfies specific conditions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2191483/constructing-a-homomorphism-from-s4-to-s3-that-satisfies-specific-conditions)

but if it's possible I'm looking for a more immediate and natural way to construct it.

Does anyone have some ideas?

Thanks in advance for your kindly help.

**Editing:**

Now it's clear how to construct the required morphism.

What about finding it **without using that H is normal**?

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/104041) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The morphism $S_3\to S_4/H,\;g\mapsto gH$ is injective (since $S_3\cap H=\{1\}$) hence bijective by a counting argument.

The composition of its inverse isomorphism $S_4/H\to S_3$ by the canonical epimorphism $S_4\to S_4/H$ gives the epimorphism you looked for.

Its direct explicit definition is : send any $h\in S_4$ to the unique $g\in hH\cap S_3.$

Comment: It definitely works but how can I prove that each class in S4/H really contains a unique element of S3? I mean, I'm quite conviced about that but it seems a bit "euristic" as an approach

Comment: Now it's perfect, thanks a lot

Comment: I inserted another proof that each class contains a unique element of $S_3$. I think it is better. I want to erase the first one.

Comment: What can I do if I want to deduce that H is normal by the fact that it is the kernel of a morphism of groups? I mean, is there any way to adapt this demonstration in order not to assume that H is normal and deducing it in retrospect after finding the ker of the morphism?

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3445868/showing-that-klein-four-group-is-a-normal-subgroup-of-s-4) is not exactly what you ask for, but may please you.

Comment: I was able to prove that H is normal in S4 by using conjugation definition, mine was just a curiosity. If there's no easy way to construct a map from S4 to S3 without assuming H is normal it's not a problem, your previous answer is fine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a suggestion: to get such a map, what you want is a group action of $S_4$ on three things.  It would be natural to look at the left-multiplication action on cosets of a subgroup of index 3/order 8 in $S_4$.  The dihedral subgroup $D_8$ of $S_4$ generated by $(1, 2, 3, 4)$ and $(1, 3)$ has order 8 (it consists of $V_4$ together with the elements $(1, 2, 3, 4), (1, 3), (2, 4)$, and $(1, 4, 3, 2)$), and it will work.

You need to show that you can realise any permutation of the three cosets of $D_8$ as left-multiplication by an element of $S_4$, and you need to check that the kernel of the action is $V_4$.  To get started, find a complete set of coset representatives of $D_8$ in $S_4$...

Comment: Sounds really interesting, I'll go through it. As a beginner in the subject I'm still wondering how I can prove that this map is actually a morphism...

Comment: you can do it directly: once you figure out exactly what you're trying to prove, it will simply be the associativity property for $S_4$.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a geometric construction.

The group of rotations of a cube is isomorphic to $S_4$. Indeed, you can view it as the action on the four diagonals of the cube.

[image]

(I took the picture from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751507/the-group-of-rigid-motions-of-the-cube-is-isomorphic-to-s-4?rq=1))

Under this action, 180 degree rotations correspond to the non-trivial elements of the Klein 4 group.

Now consider the set of pairs of opposite faces of a cube. There are three such pairs. Labelling the pairs as $\{1 , 2, 3\}$ we get an action of $S_4$ on $\{1,2,3\}$, in other words, a homomorphism $S_4 \to S_3$.

The kernel of this homomorphism is exactly the rotations of the cube that fix each of the three pairs of opposite faces - i.e. it is exactly the Klein 4 group.

Comment: Brilliant construction!